# C++ references to C-style array elements

Tags: c++, arrays, casting, reference

Are there any C++ language standards regarding how the following reference initialization would have to be implemented by a compiler?

```cpp
extern float m2( float (&fa)[3] );

void client_of_m2( ) {
   float vec[3] { 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f };
   float mag2 = m2( (float (&)[3]) vec[0] );  // odd way to call m2!
   ...
}
```

Specifically, will the way the `fa` parameter is being assigned with the zeroth element of `vec[0]` being specified explicitly, preceded by the c-style cast leave any wiggle room for how the compiler might pass that argument to the `m2` function?  Is this completely identical to a more text book call like: `float mag2 = m2( vec );`?

Comment: The cast is not needed.  All you need is `float mag2 = m2( vec );`

Comment: Why make things so difficult? `extern float m2( float *fa );` is much simpler, and does pretty much the same thing.

Comment: It's not compeletely identical but has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik the `[3]` does produce some compiler warnings when you pass an array of the wrong size (too small) and clearly shows an array of size 3 is expected.

Comment: Agree with, and thank you for the suggestions regarding better approaches.  In this case, the question was spawned from code out of a code-generator which I don't have ownership/change-control for.   What I'm trying to ascertain is if this syntax has significant drawbacks --like molbdnilo's "undefined behaviour" comment.